# Spring boot 2.7 webflux r2dbc use jasync-r2dbc-mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql, jasync-sql

When I upgrade my project from spring boot 2.6.6 to 2.7.0, use r2dbc will got the error like this:

```
2022-06-16 12:40:51.655 [][][ERROR][][db-sql-netty-thread-2] - Operator called default onErrorDropped
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/github/jasync/r2dbc/mysql/JasyncMetadata.getColumnMetadatas()Ljava/util/List; is abstract
    at com.github.jasync.r2dbc.mysql.JasyncMetadata.getColumnMetadatas(JasyncMetadata.kt) ~[jasync-r2dbc-mysql-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:266) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.RowMetadataUtils.getColumnMetadata(RowMetadataUtils.java:69) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.RowMetadataUtils.containsColumn(RowMetadataUtils.java:46) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.readFrom(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:169) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.read(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:139) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.MappingR2dbcConverter.read(MappingR2dbcConverter.java:122) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.EntityRowMapper.apply(EntityRowMapper.java:46) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.convert.EntityRowMapper.apply(EntityRowMapper.java:29) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.github.jasync.r2dbc.mysql.JasyncResult.map$lambda-1(JasyncResult.kt:38) ~[jasync-r2dbc-mysql-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:964) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:68) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:282) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage.lambda$subscribe$0(MonoCompletionStage.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.18.jar:3.4.18]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.util.FutureUtilsKt.success(FutureUtils.kt:16) ~[jasync-pool-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.mysql.MySQLConnection.succeedQueryPromise$lambda-12(MySQLConnection.kt:359) ~[jasync-mysql-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.mysql.MySQLConnection.succeedQueryPromise(MySQLConnection.kt:358) ~[jasync-mysql-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.mysql.MySQLConnection.onResultSet(MySQLConnection.kt:370) ~[jasync-mysql-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.mysql.codec.MySQLConnectionHandler.handleEOF(MySQLConnectionHandler.kt:438) ~[jasync-mysql-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.mysql.codec.MySQLConnectionHandler.channelRead0(MySQLConnectionHandler.kt:126) ~[jasync-mysql-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327) ~[netty-codec-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299) ~[netty-codec-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) ~[netty-transport-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar:4.1.77.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
```

I was using **r2dbc-mysql** before, but the response is too slow.
when I was using **r2dbc-mysql**, the i/o database response time over 3 second.
but I don't know why. and cannot find the same problem as myself.

I just use **org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository** to get info with **mysql**.

so I change to use jasync-r2dbc-mysql, but got this error above.

this is my pom.xml setting:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xxxxx</name>
    <description>xxxxxxxx</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mongo reactive -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- r2dbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  r2dbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--r2dbc mysql-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jasync-sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasync-r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency>
```

this project need to carry high throughput.
when I use **r2dbc-mysql**, the call **.cancel()** is too slow.

Comment: That version isn't compatible with the version of R2DBC in this release. So either don't upgrade, or don't use `jasync-r2dbc-mysql`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok, thank you. I think use spring boot version 2.6.8 is normal.

Comment: If that works, go for it. I suspect you have to wait for a version to support this `jasync-r2dbc-mysql`. I would also try to investigate why the `cancel` is slow and report an issue with the regular library so it can be improved. You can use a tracing tool/monitor for this or at least register an issue with the R2DBC guys who maintain the MySQL library for this.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, if I provide the api response time between two version and call **.cancel()** response log. is useful?

Comment: because this problem occur our production env. the api requests avg 250 times in one minute

Comment: No. You need to figure out **why** the `cancel` call is so slow. So basically what is the difference between the regular implementation and this one.

Comment: https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql/issues/300